# MS Access: Object required Error with SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I understand what is the meaning behind this error, but I simply dont know why is he underling my line of code, that is supposed to cause this error.

**EXPLANATION:**
What I am trying to achieve is, when you select a Company from `CompanyCombo box`, it will automaticly "filter" the `ContactCombo box` to those contacts that are from above mentioned company. 
`Companies` and `Contacts` are two different tables which are connected through Query called Companies Query (the `CompanyNr` [this is also *UniqueKey*] from Companies is connected with `CompanyNr` from Contacts).

**PART OF CODE:**

```
Private Sub CompanyCombo_Change()
    Dim sql1 As String
    ' The below code causes the Objecr required error
    sql1 = "SELECT [Contacts].[ID], [Contacts].[Contact] FROM Contacts " & _
           "WHERE [Contacts].[CompanyNr] = " & CompanyNr.Value & " ORDER BY [Contact]; "

    ContactNrCombo.RowSource = sql1
    ContactNrCombo.Requery
End Sub
```

I have a ComboBox for Companies and Contacts, and I want to write next to them the appropriate number (CompanyNr for Companies and ContactNr for Contacts)

They are connected with query.

I am quite new to the VBA, so maybe I dont see something here what could be causing the error.

**TABLES for CONTACTS  and COMPANIES:**
    Contact Table has: ID, CompanyNr, Contact
    Company Table has: CompanyNr, Company

CompanyNr are connnected via Relationships.

I really dont know what could be going wrong here. I created the ComboBox with the wizard that pops up when creating.

Please, anyone, help me out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP seems to be lacking the basic debugging skills and any help revolved around debugging this problem will be too broad.

Comment: The only object access I see is `CompanyNr`. Check that this is really the name of a control in your form.

Comment: @vba4all So what, should I copy my entire code here? Or post screenshots of the table? What do you expect - let me know, and I`ll post it here. I tried to provide as much info as I can.

Comment: [Not much](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) @AndroidNFC

Comment: @grahamj42 Yes that I also noticed, but the CompanyNr is set as Control Source for the ComboCox (I called it in my case CompanyCombo). That´s why i dont know what´s wrong..

Comment: @vba4all I added an Explanation what I want to do with the code, maybe it helps more. But I dont know what other info could be helpful in this case. The error is caused by this sub. This sub is connected to two tables and a query exists that connects those two tables.

Comment: @AndroidNFC: The best approach here is to simplify. You've got a lot going on and an fairly uninformative error message. You have two objects you're referring to and calling methods on - CompanyNr and ContactNrCombo - either of which could be spelled wrong or null which would cause the error. Simplify your method so that you are only doing something with one of them at a time and see when you get the error.

Comment: I was about to reply with the same answer as iDevlop. Glad you got the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a try, because the question does not provide enough info at the moment:
Shouldn't the WHERE line refer to CompanyCombo instead of CompanyNr ?

```
"WHERE [Contacts].[CompanyNr] = " & CompanyCombo.Value & " ORDER BY [Contact]; "
```

Comment: Thanks @iDevlop, this seemed to fix my issue. I guess I confused something in that statement. Thanks again!